# Tensorflow Object Detection: visualization_export_dir in eval_config not saving eval images

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

As the title states, I would like to save the detection vs. ground truth images of the eval from Tensorboard.

From the eval proto:

```
// Path to directory to store visualizations in. If empty, visualization
// images are not exported (only shown on Tensorboard).
optional string visualization_export_dir = 6 [default=""];
```

Therefore I have added it to my model.config file as such. Keep in mind I am working from the /Object-Detection/ directory.

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 57

  visualization_export_dir: "bevelgear_training/eval_images/"
  num_visualizations: 57
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_detection_metrics"
}
```

Training finishes as normal, I can see all the eval images in tensorboard BUT the /eval_images/ folder is empty.

Anyone get this working?

Comment: Try using the old eval.py script, in legacy folder.

Answer (score 1):

While the parameter is available in the config file, this feature is not actually supported.
Instead, you can use TensorBoard and see the evaluated images with overlaid detections under images tab.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's not implemented. Is there a way you know that will allow me to export those images from tensorboard? I need to use them for evaluation offline and I would love to be able to download 100+ images without having to do it one by one. That way I can see the images without having to fire up tensorboard every time to see the event files.

Comment: @netanel-sam do you know if there are any plans to implement this feature?

Comment: @DankMasterDan, I don't know. Maybe when TF 2.0 is released they'll fix some of the features that are not supported yet, but it's an uneducated guess.
youngEngineer, they didn't implement the connection between the configuration and the visualization functionality, but the functionality exists: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/eval_util.py#L81

Comment: Perhaps this is true in an older version, but since at least v1.12 (Nov 2018) this feature has been implemented..

Comment: This is not related to TF version, but to OD API version. Are you using the current model_main.py or the deprecated eval.py? Best to my knowledge this was an available feature in the deprecated eval.py, which is now not supported when evaluating using the current model_main.py.

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks correct, and the feature is implemented in current TensorFlow versions. This is my eval_config:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 100
  num_visualizations: 20
  visualize_groundtruth_boxes: true
  visualization_export_dir: "F:/project_name/tf-eval/"
  include_metrics_per_category: true
}
```

I get visualisations in both TensorBoard and saved to file. It could be that your relative paths are causing an issue, although that normally is not a problem in the `.config` file. The export directory must exist - otherwise no images will be output.

Comment: Seems like it is not working in the current version (1.13)... I even put in the full path to make sure. Weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

append the lines :

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import os
    vutils.save_image_array_as_png(sbys_image[0], os.path.join(eval_config.visualization_export_dir, 'eval_{}_{}'.format(i,j) + ".png"))
```

after the code should look like :

```
  for j, sbys_image in enumerate(sbys_image_list):
    tf.compat.v2.summary.image(
        name='eval_side_by_side_{}_{}'.format(i, j),
        step=global_step,
        data=sbys_image,
        max_outputs=eval_config.num_visualizations)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import os
    vutils.save_image_array_as_png(sbys_image[0], os.path.join(eval_config.visualization_export_dir, 'eval_{}_{}'.format(i,j) + ".png"))
```

at model_lib_v2.py line number 992

be careful, not to fix your cloned file. model_lib_v2.py should be in the path something looks like /python-3.6/pakages/object_detection/util....

thx